EF Model with a linked property on two columns, one would be hard coded
I have a setting/lookup (Settings) table that has 3 main columns, Category, DataID, and DataValue.
Then I have an HR table with an employees basic data.  For this question I will use TITLE as the example.  The Title column is an ID that links to the DataID column in the settings table.  However, on it's own the DataID column is not unique.  We also need to provide a Category, e.g. Where DataId = 2 and Category = "HR-Title".
In Entity Framework, when creating the linked property we KNOW the category will always be "HR-Title", but only DataID is provided in the HR table.
So if I have something like the following as the EF HR Model, how can I force EF to use the correct Category?
public class Employee {
  public int TitleId { get; set; }
  public Settings Title { get; set; }
// more properties
}

public class Setting {
  public string Category { get; set; }
  public string DataId { get; set; }
  public string DataValue { get; set; }
}

For reference this is a C#, .Net 6 class library project using EF core 7.

Your desired approach violates normalized database design and will probably not be supportable with EF. You can't enforce relational integrity in the database with your Settings table unless you have data properties to specify the relationship. If Title in this case is something like JobTitle, then you really need a JobTitle table, not a generic Setting table.

I couldn't agree more... sadly this is a very old database that has "mutated" over nearly 20 years.  There is a complete remake in the works but it will take time and the legacy version needs maintaining in the meantime.
